# "invalid command-line parameter" error while trying to make a hello world example for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I just decided to start developing apps for Android and I encountered some problems.
I get this error when I try to build a hello world example from http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html#top:

> [2011-07-17 00:22:46 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter:
>   Files\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe. [2011-07-17 00:22:46
>   - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
>   [2011-07-17 00:22:46 - Emulator] please use -help for more information

I have followed everything in that tutorial, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

There is a bug with paths. You have your SDK in C:\Program Files, but the sdk can't work with spaces in the path (this is why you only see "parameter: Files\Android\..."). Install it into a location without spaces, e.g. directly to C:\android-sdk. I think it's ok to cut & paste the complete folder into the new location and just change the path in the eclipse preferences.

Comment: ^^This. The newest version of the SDK cares if you have spaces in the path, yet no older version does. This is a known issue and hopefully will be resolved in the newest version of the SDK.

Comment: I've found a few idiosyncrasies when the following registry path is not updated in the registry:  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android SDK Tools\Path`  Update this value as well and all should be well.