# Running first Android application - error message

Tags: android

I am getting this error when I am trying to launch my first *Hello World* Android application. I am doing the tutorial based on *[Sams Teach Yourself Android Application Development in 24 Hours](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321673352)*.How can I resolve this?

> [2011-08-18 02:33:28 - droidapp] ------------------------------
>   [2011-08-18 02:33:28 - droidapp] Android Launch!
>   [2011-08-18 02:33:28 - droidapp] adb is running normally.
>   [2011-08-18 02:33:28 - droidapp] Performing com.droid.app.DroidappActivity activity launch
>   [2011-08-18 02:33:28 - droidapp] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'firstdroid' is not available. Launching new emulator.
>   [2011-08-18 02:33:28 - droidapp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'firstdroid'
>
> **[2011-08-18 02:33:30 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter:
>   Files\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe. [2011-08-18 02:33:30
>   - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
>   [2011-08-18 02:33:30 - Emulator] please use -help for more
>   information**

Comment: You got a whitespace in your sdk path. Remove that. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720652/invalid-command-line-parameter-error-while-trying-to-make-a-hello-world-example/6720681#6720681.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720652/invalid-command-line-parameter-error-while-trying-to-make-a-hello-world-example/6720681#6720681

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the path of the SDK your path to `Program Files\Android\android-sdk tools/emulator-arm.exe`. Put the SDK directly in the drive, that is, `d:\Android\android-sdk-tools\emulator-arm.exe`.

Note: also remove spaces from the path by renaming the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) and the Android plugin to make this via a graphical user interface. That would be better for a newcomer.

Comment: I am using eclipse and the android plugin.