# Android SDK issue

Tags: android, android-emulator

So, I just bought a computer with windows 7 64 bit and installed Android SDK on it for Android development. When I try to start any of the virtual android machines, I get an error saying that I should use @foo instead of foo. It will not let me boot any of the virtual android machines. I have installed java, and before anyone asks, I just spent a good amount of money on this rig, and the benchmarks on it are incredible, so tech is not an issue. Now I have read some android books, and I know that has to do something with calling programs. I have looked in the google android SDK troubleshoot for this problem, but nothing came up on this problem. Did I install it wrong? Does the SDK only work with eclipse conjoined to its hip? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your path doesn't have any spaces in it. Save it in C:\android_sdk or something like that.

Comment: make sure it doesn't have spaces when installing it?

Comment: this is often the problem. you dont want to save it under something like `Program Files` since that has a space in it. Check what directory it is installed in

Comment: Yeah, I've had this exact problem. Just make sure that wherever you install it to, the file path does not contain any spaces in it. That means you will have to change the installation directory from its default in `Program Files` to some other folder, probably one you made yourself. If you already have the SDK installed, you can just cut and paste it to a suitable directory rather than having to uninstall and reinstall it.

Answer (score 2):

Try and start it from the command line rather from the GUI. On windows I use a .bat file as

```
cd c:\program files\Android\android-sdk\tools

emulator -avd avd3 -sdcard MySdCardFile.img
```

you might get better error information

Comment: what is the sdcard MYSDCardFile.img? how do I make one?

Answer (score 1):

ya sure it is problem of path of your SDK for more information refer this [Running first Android application - error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099479/running-first-android-application-error-message/7102100#7102100)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through a new installation you can query the 8.3 name of the directory containing a space on the command line with "dir /X".

Replace the wrong path with that short name in Eclipses Android SDK location setting (Window/Properties/Android).