# AVD in Eclipse not working in Emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am in the process of putting together an android application for a client using Eclipse Classic with the Android SDK.

The problem I have is the AVD is not running when I start it, just showing this message.

> invalid command-line parameter: Files. Hint: use '@foo' to launch a
>   virtual device named 'foo'. please use -help for more information*

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look where you have installed the android SDK. This means where is your SDKManager.exe file.

The path up to that file should not have more then 2 folder.

In my computer the path for SDKMAnager.exe is " C:\Android\android-sdk-windows".
In android-sdk-windows folder everything is there like addons, docs, tools, SDKManager.exe etc.

If you have installed anywhere like " C:\Programe Files\MyFolder\Android\android-sdk-windows" then it will not run.

Remove all folder and remain with 2 folder like I have described above.

Answer (score 0):

Ya it is happen when you had not installed SDK properly or see this [Running first Android application - error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099479/running-first-android-application-error-message/7102100#7102100) .

Answer (score 0):

Please remove space on android sdk path.